# new intent after click callback

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onclick

I have a listview and when it clicks on a certain option I want it to create a new intent. Like a menu item. This is my first time working with list views, so I'm probably just missing the right way to do this, but is there an easy fix?

```
private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) viewClicked;
        Toast.makeText(main.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(textView.getText().toString() == "my Profile"){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), myProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

> cannot resolve method 'getapplicationcontext'

Comment: Looks like you are comparing Strings wrong. You should use `.equals()` instead of `==`. If there is another problem then you need to be more clear on exactly what is/isn't happening

Comment: @codeMagic This question has little to do with string comparison.. the `IF` surely needs to be fixed but the actual question is about the error `cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()' hence the question is different.. imho

Comment: @FredMaggiowski yep, I missed that. Thanks for pinging me and pointing it out. I will reopen. The String comparison will be the next issue most likely. Bahamit, use `viewClicked.getContext()` instead.

Comment: No prob :) yeah, the string comparison **must** to be fixed

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I have taken your input into consideration and I got my application running again. However, now I have a new problem: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 108000012 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 46MB until OOM... 
I'm running out of memory. Do I have to close out of my previous intents/activities?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `this.getApplicationContext()` since you're inside a `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` and there,`this` doesn't have that method.

You should create a class field containing the application context and use it or use `viewClicked.getContext()` as suggested by @codeMagic.

Also, as you might have been read in the comments, you should use `.equals` for string comparison. The `==` operator is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myProfile.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where `MainActivity` is he activity where you implemented `onItemClick()`.
You should replace it by your activity name.